# How to open screenshot in "markup" mode by default?

Tags: preview, quicklook, markup

I recently updated to Ventura and I lost a feature I didn't realize I depend so much on. Previously when I took a screen shot (typically using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> ), when I clicked the floating thumbnail it would open the Preview but already in the markup editor.

[image]

Unfortunately, I am now forced to click the markdown icon every single time which is frustrating;  nearly every time I take a screenshot I intend to add some type of annotation.

Is there a way to restore this or change the settings?

***Note:** I have noticed that my phone opens in markup each time but I would prefer to use my current device to make the annotations*

[image]

Comment: I would love to find a fix for this...

Comment: Great question. I have the same issue. @LeopoldKristjansson Mention it to Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Comment: I've often wondered about the expertise of those who design systems for Apple. Some of their design choices truly puzzle me. I've struggled with this particular issue for months. It's frustrating that it requires two clicks: one for the editor and one for the action. Is there a way to assign a hotkey to it? I'm finding it hard to cope with this

Comment: I feel your pain. I went searching for an answer and as of today, still nothing. Dave over at MGG Discord recommended using "Shottr". It's free (30 days, but cheap to buy), and it's WAY more robust than the built-in option. I just started using it, and holy Sh@#%! it's great. Thanks for the question because it was bugging the crap out of me as well.

Link:  https://shottr.cc/

Comment: Have you thought about making a shortcut that will automate this for you?

Comment: @jel888 Interesting idea, I'll have to try shortcuts.