# Quick Look markup toolbar is no longer shown by default

Tags: macos, screen-capture, quicklook, ocr

I'm on Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400).

In the past I was able to take a screenshot (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>), click on the thumbnail in the corner of my screen opening the "Quick Look", and immediately begin drawing on the screenshot. The markup toolbar was always enabled by default.

Recently, the toolbar is never enabled, so I have to click on the [image] button to display it, then click on the [image] button to select the "Sketch" tool.

This is two clicks more than before!

I assume that this is due to the addition of the ability to copy text from any image, as the text selection cursor is now the default. But I use the Sketch tool hundreds of times more than the text selection tool.

Is it possible to change back to the old default behaviour, where Quick Look defaults to the Sketch tool?

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451530/how-to-open-screenshot-in-markup-mode-by-default but no answers yet.

Comment: Great question. I have the same issue. Mention it to Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a macro or something of the sort, or just live with it.