# Screenshot tool default draw

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I am using the default mac OS screenshot tool in Ventura 13.1.

When I take a screenshot of a section of the screen (using the shortcut Cmd+Shift+4) and then click the screenshot thumbnail in the bottom right corner of the screen, I am taken to the editor that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the screenshot editor]

Very often I want to mark up this screenshot by drawing into this. I have to click 2 buttons: the "start editing" in the top-right corner of this editor, and then "freeform drawing" in the top-left corner.

This takes two more clicks than I was used to: I could *swear* the drawing was the default action in some previous mac OS version!

Is there an option to bring it back? The screenshot tool settings contain nothing of sorts.

Comment: Duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451650/quick-look-markup-toolbar-is-no-longer-shown-by-default and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451530/how-to-open-screenshot-in-markup-mode-by-default but no answers yet

Comment: Thanks, yes this is a duplicate, sorry I could find it neither with Google nor did SO show me the duplicate as I was writing it up.

Comment: @vektor Great question. I have the same issue. Mention it to Apple: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html